# Django redirect not working?

Tags: django

If a user wants to delete the post I want to return them back to their accounts page, however, with the code below it returns them back to the edit page where they can edith their posts. It doesn't delete the post?

```
def airline_delete(request, id=None):
  instance = get_object_or_404(Airline, id=id)
  instance.delete()
  return redirect('upload_overview')
```

**url**

```
#account/upload/edit/ (Edit airline)
url(r'^account/airlines/edit/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$', airline_update, name='airline_update'),

#account/upload/delete/(Delete airline)
    url(r'^account/airlines/edit/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$', airline_delete, name='airline_delete'),
```

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Your URLs are the same, so only airline_update will ever be called. You should probably make the delete URL contain "delete" instead of "edit".

Comment: Such a simple fix. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use same url you could use class based view with `put` (for edit) and `delete` (for delete) methods which would use same url pattern. 
But in that case you should also call with appropriate `HTTP` methods `PUT` for `put` method and `DELETE` for `delete` method.